# Различие зависимых и независимых выборок

Tags: статистика

У меня есть выборка из 100 организаций и два показателя - численность работников пенсионного возраста и численность работников с высшим образованием. Формулирую вопрос для исследования - влияет ли численность работников с высшим образованием на численность работников пенсионного возраста? При выборе статистического метода мне данную выборку определять как зависимую? Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Звучит как влияние количества пиратов на глобальное потепление

Comment: Возможно. Но я бы хотел услышать мнение, зависимые в данном случае выборки, или нет. Это как раз тот случай, когда одному случаю из выборки X соответствует один и только один случай из выборки Y и наоборот?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Исследованием" это я бы поостерегся назвать.
Элементарная задача на анализ наличия корреляции  двух величин.
Ну, например:
[http://www.machinelearning.ru/wiki/index.php?title=Коэффициент_корреляции_Пирсона](http://www.machinelearning.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%9F%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Про какое "*Различие* (???) *зависимых* (множественное число?)  *и независимых* (множественное число??) *выборок* (множественное число???)" идет речь - загадка, т.к. выборок у вас одна, величин две и они могут быть сильно коррелированы  (положительно или отрицательно) или слабо коррелированы.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ. Согласен с Вами, название темы и приведённый пример не соответствуют друг другу. Разрешите я приведу 3 примера, а Вы ответите, прав я или нет. 1. Есть две группы организаций, я хочу выяснить, различается ли в этих группах доля работников с высшим образованием. Для этого применяю t критерий стьюдента для несвязанных выборок.

Comment: 2. Есть две группы организаций и доля работников пенсионного возраста в организациях. Изменилось пенсионное законодательство. Есть доля работников после изменения пенсионного законодательства. Хочу выяснить, повлияло ли изменение пенсионного законодательства на долю работников пенсионного возраста в ТЕХ ЖЕ САМЫХ организациях. Применяю t критерий стьюдента для связанных выборок. 3. Если групп организаций больше чем две, применяю дисперсионный анализ (соответственно, тоже для несвязанных или связанных выборок).

Comment: И ещё один вопрос. Как понимать определение для связанных выборок - "когда одному случаю из выборки X соответствует один и только один случай из выборки Y и наоборот"? Если можно, с примером. Благодарю Вас!

Comment: Ну, благодарность на этом сайте выражается несколько по другому. Теперь отвечаю на ваши вопросы. 1- Да. 2. -Да. 3.-Да.4.- Проще всего понимать связные выборки, как такие, в которых всегда точно известно, какие значения КАЖДЫЙ из объектов имел "до" и "после". Понятно, что при этом количество элементов должна быть равной.  Те-же самые выборки, но в которых вы просто "забыли", от какого объекта взяты значения  -  это уже несвязанные выборки. Причем количество значений в каждой выборке может быть различными.  Надеюсь ответил. Если нет - задавайте вопросы.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное за ответы! Необходимо больше практических задач, надеюсь тогда в голове "устаканится" понимание разницы между связанными и не связанными выборками. Простите, а как благодарность выражается на этом сайте?

Comment: Если Вы имеете в виду под благодарностью оценку Вашего ответа, то я бы с удовольствием её поставил, только не могу разобраться как.

Comment: Слева от ответа есть стрелочки "вверх"-"вниз", между ними циферка. Если ответ понравился - жмем стрелочку "вверх". Если он принят вами за ответ - жмем соответствующую кнопочку.